# Why can we always choose Riemannian metrics to be symmetric?

Tags: manifolds, general-relativity

I'm reading **General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists** by **Hobson**, **Efstathiou** and **Lasenby**, [here](https://mobt3ath.com/uplode/books/book-48253.pdf), and I'm stuck in this part of the book (chapter 2, page 32), where it says that Riemannian metrics can always be chosen to be symmetric. I don't understand why do we interchange the indices as mentioned in the underlined phrase. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can think of it as the fact that the inner product matrix is symmetric. $U \cdot V = V \cdot U$

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $\alpha=(b+c)/2$ then $$ax^2+bxy+cyx+dy^2=ax^2+\alpha xy+\alpha yx+dy^2.$$